# How can I run multiple UI tests in a single browser?

Tags: java, selenium, junit, testng, jboss-arquillian

first of all: I'm a student and I am trying to learn UI testing (I only understand the basics). I want to run multiple UI tests without closing the browser after every single test. I am using TestNG, arquillian and graphene, but I don't mind to switch to JUnit if that helps. What I've got so far is:

```
public class ParentTest extends Arquillian
{
}


public class Test2and1 extends ParentTest
{
    @Test(dependsOnGroups = {"test1"})
    public void test2and1()
    {
        assertFalse(driver.getTitle().equals("123"));
    }
}

public class Test1 extends ParentTest
{
    @Test(groups = {"test1"})
    public void test1()
    {
        assertFalse(driver.getTitle().equals("123"));
    }
}
```

What I've tried as well is to bring the driver to the superclass `ParentTest`, but that gives the same result. I've searched the whole internet, but their solutions don't seem to work on my situation :(

Comment: Best practice is to use one browser per test. It keeps each run clean and less likely to have different scripts affect each other resulting in more consistent results.

Answer (score 1):

Arquillion Drone provides three life cycle for webdriver management. They are method, class and deployment level scope. Default scope is class scope. So Webdriver instance created and destroyed at class level.

Try with Deployment scoped drone with dummy deploy class. I didn't tried this.

```
public class ParentTest extends Arquillian {

   @Deployment(name = "dummydeploy")
   public static Archive deploy() {
      return ShrinkWrap.create(Archive.class);
   }

   @Drone
   @OperateOnDeployment("dummydeploy")
   WebDriver static foo;

}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your explaination. This makes it a little more clear for me. Tried what u told me, but then driver stays null. See the code in my edited question for what I've tried :)

Comment: Dont edit the question with answers. It will mislead that I didn't  answered your question. Please revert back. I will try that  and will share you the working example

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by creating a singleton webdriver object and using getter in your test methods:

```
public class SingletonWebDriver {

    private static WebDriver singletonWebDriver;

    public static WebDriver getDriver() {
        if (singletonWebDriver == null) {
            singletonWebDriver = new ChromeDriver();
        }
        return singletonWebDriver;
    }
}


public class ParentTest extends Arquillian {

        protected WebDriver getDriver() {
            return SingletonWebDriver.getDriver();
        }
    }

public class Test1 extends ParentTest {

        @Test(groups = {"test1"})
        public void test1() {
            assertFalse(getDriver().getTitle().equals("123"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: When I try this I can't use Graphene anymore. When I try to run `Graphene.goTo(AnyPage.class)` I get the error  `There is no context available for qualifier org.jboss.arquillian.drone.api.annotation.Default. Available contexts are [].`